# Get the changed "this.model" attribute value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

A Backbone.js noob question. The code I'm working with currently looks like this

My DataModel Model :

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Defaults attribute values
        defaults : {
            completed : false,
        },
        url : 'path/to/my/data.json',
    });
    return DataModel;
});
```

And I have another Model called `ServiceModel` which is an instance of `DataModel` which looks like this

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', '../models/DataModel'], function($, _, Backbone, DataModel) {

    // SupplierService as an Object Literal.
    SupplierService = {};

    // Instatiate the DataModel()
    var ServiceModel = new DataModel();
    var that = ServiceModel;

    ServiceModel.fetch().done(function() {
        data = ServiceModel.toJSON();

        SupplierService.figures.calculate(data)
    });

    SupplierService.figures = (function() {
        // I set completed to true here
        function constructor(d) {
        // some work done here
            that.set({
                completed : true,
            });
        }

        return {
            calculate : function(d) {
                constructor(d)
            },
        }
    })();

    return ServiceModel;
});
```

My View :

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', '../../models/ServiceModel'], function($, _, Backbone, ServiceModel) {
    var AppVIew = Backbone.View.extend({
        model : ServiceModel,
        initialize : function() {
            console.log(this.model.get('completed'));
        },
    });
    return AppVIew;
});
```

My Output prints `false` and not `true`. This is how it looks when I print `this.model`

[image]

Why is it that when I `this.model.get('completed')` I get `false`.

I am doing the correct thing?? Any help/advice will be appreciated, to go further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `View:initialize` you have got **default** model value, then in a couple of seconds `ServiceModel.fetch()` **has finished request** and updated model value with `true`

From my perspective:
1 move out `DataModel` from `SupplierService`
2 rewrite `SupplierService` in the same way as `DataModel`
3 pass `SupplierService` as dependency to `AppVIew`
4 in `AppView:initialize` put

```
serviceModel = new ServiceModel();
supplierService = new SupplierService();

serviceModel.fetch().done(function() {
   var data = serviceModel.toJSON();

   supplierService.figures.calculate(data)
});
```